# 本番PayPalアカウントでIPNの警告メール

Tags: paypal

PayPalアカウントに「PayPal IPN URLに通知できなかった」旨の警告メールが来ました。
しかし、該当URLは普通にアクセスできます。なぜこのメールが届いたのかわかりません…。考えられる点としては、IPNで何らかのエラーが発生したときにHTTPステータスを404として返すようにしていました。これが原因なのかわかる方はいますでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PayPalは、IPNの接続先から200以外のレスポンスを受け取った場合は、送信できなかったと判断し、IPNを再送します。
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/
IPNからのデータが正常にとれている場合、レスポンスは200を返すようにしてください。
この警告メールを受信した後も同じ状態が続く場合、PayPalは送信をやめてしまうようなので注意してください。

Comment: なるほど。であればすぐに200で返るように直します。ありがとうございます。